# Create Sequelize Query, Multiple Innerjoins and Wheres across multiple tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have created a successful mysql query that joins 2 tables that have foreign keys to each other. I got almost everything to work in Sequelize other than getting the user attached to the responses. My query does that successfully but I cannot understand how to get it.

This is my mysql query that works specifically gets the "users" that has the same id as the response "user_id"

```
SELECT *
FROM meetup_db.posts p
INNER JOIN meetup_db.responses r
INNER JOIN meetup_db.users u
WHERE p.id = r.post_id AND
r.user_id = u.id
```

This is my sequelize query that almost works but does not give me back the user in each response where user_id = id

```
const dbPostData = await Posts.findOne({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    include: [
        { model: Users },
        {
            model: Responses,
            include: {
                model: Users,
                where: { id: Responses.user_id }, //this is the line in question i need the user that has the same id as the Response.user_id
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The sequelize correctlys outputs everything but the user, heres a sample output as you can see the response has **Users** listed inside but the users just show as **[Object]**

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'BBQ At My House!!',
  description: 'Hey gang! Im having a BBQ at my house! I hope all can attend!!',
  upvotes: 44,
  location: '2113 Main St. Austin, TX.',
  date_occuring: 2021-08-04T18:00:00.000Z,
  created_at: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
  edited: false,
  user_id: 1,
  createdAt: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
  User: {
    id: 1,
    username: 'Jennifer Wylan',
    email: 'jwylan@gmail.com',
    password: 'ewfchijwnsj',
    image_url: '/assets/fake-pfp/fakeperson1.png'
  },
  Responses: [
    {
      id: 4,
      response: 'Im in there like swimwear!',
      user_id: 4,
      post_id: 1,
      createdAt: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
      User: [Object] //these lines right here need to look like the above User: {} Object
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      response: 'weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      user_id: 1,
      post_id: 1,
      createdAt: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-08-06T04:42:01.000Z,
      User: [Object] //these lines right here need to look like the above User: {} Object
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So it worked already.
In my terminal the output of responses was showing the User key as **[Object]**
... Turns out when its like 3 tables deep the terminal just shows [Object] but it was actually there already, you also dont need the `where:` because it already looks for the foreign key